# Getting jakarta.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found error when attempting to navigate to JSP page from index

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jakarta-ee, jersey

POM XL dependencies

```
  <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Client class

```
package com.estore.test;

import java.net.URI;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;

import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

public class TestClient {
    
    WebTarget target;
    
    public TestClient() {
        
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:1040/RESTfulWSDemo").build();
        target = client.target(uri);
    }
    
    public String getPlainResponse() {
        
        String response = target.path("rest").path("user").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Servlet Mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>RESTfulWSDemo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyRESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.estore.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyRESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

JSP page

```
<%@page import="com.estore.test.TestClient"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My REST Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3> Testing RESTful Service</h3>
    
    <%!
        TestClient client = new TestClient();
    
    %>
    Plain Response: <%= client.getPlainResponse() %> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Service class

```
package com.estore.rest;

import java.util.Date;

//import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/user")
public class UserService {
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String registerUserWithPlainResponse() {
        String response = "stuff";
        return response;
    }
}
```

When I run the project on an apache-tomcat 9 server, I can access the landing page (http://localhost:1040/RESTfulWSDemo/) perfectly fine and can see the index.html elements but get a 404 error when trying to navigate to the JSP page.

Earlier I was getting a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found" error but resolved that by adding the HK2 dependency. Now the project cannot find the service properly?

I would like to get a plain text response = "stuff". Any help is appreciated.